# Corda is it possible to issue and consume state in same flow

Tags: corda

I am trying to do simple fund transfer from one account to another account using simple state. 2 Flows have been created one for issue of transfer request with cash transfer and flow created to just consumed that transaction. My question is, is it possible to transfer and consume state in one flow ?

As per my opinion transaction must be consumed after transfer but also want to show it on UI.

Corda RPCQuery allowed to bring information of unconsumed states only, if I consume above transaction, is there way to show consumed transactions last state?

Answer (score 1):

`CordaRPCOps` allows you to query for unconsumed states, consumed states, or both. Here's a simple way of querying for all states:

```
val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
val results = proxy.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(criteria)
```

To show the last consumed state, you could retrieve all the consumed states in descending order of consumption and grab the first one, as follows:

```
val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
val sortColumn = Sort.SortColumn(SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.VaultStateAttribute.CONSUMED_TIME), Sort.Direction.DESC)
val sorting = Sort(listOf(sortColumn))
val results = proxy.vaultQueryBy<Obligation>(criteria, sorting = sorting)
val lastConsumedState = results.states[0]
```

Comment: Yes but it will give all states, needs to show last consumed state...also is it possible that output state created in one flow becomes input state same flow?

Comment: Consuming a state in the same flows where you created it is fine. I've updated the answer to grab the last consumed state.

Answer (score 0):

- From any flow, you need to call *FinalityFlow*, in order to notarize
  and record the transaction in individual parties' vault. So I think
  after the issuance (or transfer), you need to call *FinalityFlow*
  first. Only then you can use the issued state as input for the new
  transaction.
- The notary is responsible for avoiding the double spend
  of the input state in any transaction. So you can not use any newly
  issued state (as input to new transaction), until the  notary is aware
  of it.
- Thus I think in your case, you will need to call *FinalityFlow* twice, once after each transaction (i.e. issuance & consumption).